# SharePoint Online, Migrate related Flows and Power Apps

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, migration, flow, powerapp

Are there some tools that allow to migrate SharePoint + Flows and PowerApps between tenants? I know there is [Saketa](https://saketa.com/migrator/) and [AvePoint](https://www.avepoint.com/products/cloud/management) (I suppose free versions could do something too), but what about Flows and Power Apps, how do You migrate them?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both **Microsoft Flow and PowerApps supports Export and Import** functionalities to migrate them across another tenant or another environments.

You can find the Microsoft official documentation for the same in below links:

1. [Migrate PowerApps between environments and tenants](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/environment-and-tenant-migration).
2. [Export and import your flows across environments with packaging](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/import-export-bap-packages/).

Comment: Thank You @Ganesh! So I should use third-party tools and then migrate flows and apps separately..

Comment: Welcome. Yes, you can use any tool like ShareGate, AvePoint, Saketa, Dell Migration Suite (there are many 3rd party tools), etc to migrate SharePoint contents and export-import flows and PowerApps.